# Can I see which Twitter user is currently logged in?

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

They are not OAuthed with my site but are logged into Twitter on that browser. Any way for me to know their Twitter username? Cookies.. anything?

Comment: What do you need to do with the information?  If you don't actually need the information but want to just display something in the browser that respects the current login information, you may be able to just embed a Twitter widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless something is very broken or Twitter has explicitly provided an API for that purpose, no.  Not through cookies at least.

Cookies are sandboxed to the domain that created them.  No cross-domain access to cookies is allowed.